# What are the $Recycle.bin folders and their contents on each HDD despite the recycle bin being empty?

Tags: windows-server-2008, recycle-bin

What are the `$Recycle.bin` folders and their contents on each HDD despite the Recycle bin being empty?

I can actually <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> them. What are these, some of them are huge.

This is on **Windows Server 2008**.

[image: screenshot of Recycle.bin's contents]

Comment: What file browser are you using? It looks interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are the recycle bins of other users.

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot of sense; it's what I was thinking actually.

Comment: In fact the start of the file name is the [SID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the user it belongs to